# selecting specific mysql connection from multiple conection

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x, flask

code:

```
def before_request():
   try:
    g.db = mysql.connector.connect(user=user1,password=pass1, host=hos1,
                                    database=testdb1)
      g.db1 = mysql.connector.connect(user=user2,password=pass2, host=host2,
                                    database=testdb2)

@app.route('/user/<db>', methods=['POST'])
def insert(db):
  body=request.json
  try:
      #Http request for inserting  data into testdb1:"curl 'http://localhost:5000/user/**testdb1**' testdb1 is the database".
 same way ##Http request for inserting data into testdb2:"curl 'http://localhost:5000/user/**testdb2**' testdb2 is 2nd database".

      #code for inserting data into database(testdb1/testdb2)  according to http request.
```

Everything is working fine but the problem is when i am sending (http request)
for lets say for inserting data into **testdb1**.then the connection to both of the databases get opened.But i want that only the requested database connection should get opened not both.

Question:1.What changes i need to make that only one connection get opened?
2.Is it possible that to  have g.db as a connection variable ,which store both connection and when http request comes for the database.Let say for testdb1 then only that connection get opened?

Answer (score 0):

You should set do it like this. when you start your server, you make two global connection for doing sth or like that:
For example,

```
conn1 = None
conn2 = None


def connection1():
   global conn1
   if conn1 is None:
        conn1 = ...
   return conn1
```

if u want to sql,

```
 from initConnection import conn1, conn2
 conn1.execute(sql) or conn2.execute()
```

Only one connection1 or connection2 is using.

Comment: can you please explain it little bit more?

Comment: This will ensure that the global only a database connection, when you want to use, only need to import, in the use of conn.exeute and other operations can be. First part is initConnection.py.

Comment: Otherwise when you use conn, you make a new conn. It could make too much connection.